# Construct $D,E$ on $AB,AC$ that $BD=DE=EC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Construct $D,E$ on $AB,AC$ that $BD=DE=EC$

**My attempt**:I tried to solved a special case that the triangle is isosceles triangle.In that it seems to be easy because $BD=EC$ will give us parallel lines but I can't solve that case too.

Comment: Do you mean "*construct*" as in straightedge-and-compass construction, or calculating the respective length? If the latter, just use the law of cosines twice in $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ADE$.

Comment: @dxiv using straightedge-and-compass construction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $BD=DE=EC=x$.

Thus, by law of cosines for v$\Delta ADE$ we obtain
$$x^2=(b-x)^2+(c-x)^2-2(b-x)(c-x)\cos\alpha$$ or
$$(1-2\cos\alpha)x^2-2(b+c)(1-\cos\alpha)x+a^2=0.$$

If $\alpha=60^{\circ}$ then $x=\frac{a^2}{b+c}$, which easy to construct.

If $\alpha>60^{\circ}$ we obtain a quadratic equation of $x$ with two positive roots, which easy to construct.

If $\alpha<60^{\circ}$ we obtain a quadratic equation of $x$ with one positive root, which easy to construct again.

Comment: But I need a straightedge-and-compass construction.

Comment: @Taha Akbari $\alpha$, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are given. Since this quadratic equation of $x$, we can construct $x$ and it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather you are basically trying to do is cut the leg of a triangle into 3 equal pieces. You should be able to very slightly modify the steps on [this](https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/construct-segment3.html) page to complete this task. All I'd do is instead of drawing a random line from point $B$ in step one is just extend segment $AB$ into a ray and use that.

Comment: I dont think taha wants to trisect a side, instead, given lines AB and AC, he wants to construct D on AB and E on AC, so that DB is equal to EC and DE.